# Upgraded server now class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu not working

Tags: functions, server

my server just upgrades at Dreampress and it appears to be throwing errors to the log.
`: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Declaration of My_Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL) in /home/wp_bizvdr/ctisinc.com/wp-content/themes/ctis/functions.php on line 5',`

Since it happens on every page load, its adding up to the log and potentially broke our site for some time. At least that is what Dreamhost is telling us.

This is the code its referring to I think. And I seems to be written correctly but wanted to get your take.

`class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu { function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args = array() ) { $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth); $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n"; } }` 
Any ideas?

Comment: In your function declaration, the `$depth` needs to defined as `$depth = 0`. I.e. The original function made it optional by setting a default value, and so should your function.

Comment: Thanks Sally CJ - Something like this class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {  
 function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {  
  $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);   
  $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu dropit\">\n";   } 
}

Comment: Yes, and if my (revised) answer answered the question, I'd appreciate it if you can mark my answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, (and as I said in the comments) in your function declaration, **the `$depth` parameter should be defined as `$depth = 0`**. And that's because *the [original function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_lvl/#source) (or class method) made it optional* by setting a default value, so you should also *do the same*:

```php
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
```

And if you wonder why so or why the warning was thrown by PHP, then check the PHP manual about "[Signature compatibility rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)" which says:

> When overriding a method, its signature must be compatible with the
> parent method. Otherwise, a fatal error is emitted, or, prior to PHP
> 8.0.0, an **`E_WARNING`** level error is generated. A signature is compatible if it respects the
> [variance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php)
> rules, makes a mandatory parameter optional, and if any new parameters
> are optional. This is known as the Liskov Substitution Principle, or
> LSP for short. The
> [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor),
> and `private` methods are exempt from these signature compatibility
> rules, and thus won't emit a fatal error in case of a signature
> mismatch.

And on that page, there are actually examples demonstrating that a child method *which removes a parameter, or makes an optional parameter mandatory, is not compatible* with the parent method.

So I hope that helps. :)